# Custom serializer with fallback to default serialization

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I have a case where an object might need to get serialized in different ways. Specifically, a REST endpoint is taking a header, and if the header is true, we serialize one way, if false, we serialize in another. I thought a custom serializer might be perfect for this if we put the header property in the object, but am running into a bit of trouble using it.

(Note that because of some generics being used and the way the code is structured, just creating a different object would require a lot of re-factoring, so I'm trying to find a quicker solution.)

For example, my serializer looks like this:

```
public class FooSerializer extends StdSerializer<Foo>
{
    @Override
    public void serialize(
        final Foo foo,
        final JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
        final SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
        throws IOException
    {
        if (foo.isFlattened())
        {
            jsonGenerator.writeObject(flatten(foo));
        }
        else
        {
            jsonGenerator.writeObject(foo);
        }
    }

    private Map<String,Object> flatten(Foo foo)
    {
        // ... some logic that builds the Map...
    }
}
```

And the class being serialized would be annotated accordingly:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = FooSerializer.class)
public class Foo
{
    // ... things...
}
```

The problem became obvious almost immediately: `jsonGenerator.writeObject` calls the `ObjectMapper` to serialize the object... which will then call my serializer again, giving us a lovely infinite loop and a stack overflow eventually.

The only option I can think of to work around this is to use reflection, loop over the object's properties, and write them to a new object using the `jsonGenerator`. This feels like overkill, especially when Jackson should be able to do it for me. The problem is that I can't find a way to tell the `ObjectMapper` to ignore the serializer on the class.

Is there a better way of doing this? I'm thinking I could create a custom `ObjectMapper` that somehow ignores the serializer annotated on the class, and use that as the `jsonGenerator`'s codec... but not entirely sure what lever to pull on the `ObjectMapper`.

Answer (score 1):

`Jackson` allows to register custom serialiser on many different ways. One of them is to use `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerModifier` class which allows to create custom serialiser, but also we can use, if needed, base serialiser which is available there.

Above problem looks like a good example of `OOP` problem where we can decouple `POJO`, it's logic and serialisation process. Serialiser should not know how to convert object to `Map`. It should only have serialisation logic. Let's introduce `POJO` and interface used by serialiser:

```
interface Flattenable {

    boolean isFlattened();

    Map<String, Object> flatten();
}

class Foo implements Flattenable {

    private boolean flattened;
    private int id;

    public Foo(boolean flattened, int id) {
        this.flattened = flattened;
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> flatten() {
        Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put("id", getId());
        map.put("random", ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextDouble());

        return map;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isFlattened() {
        return flattened;
    }

    public void setFlattened(boolean flattened) {
        this.flattened = flattened;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Now, we can easily handle another types by implementing `Flattenable` interface. Serialisation logic would be the same. Custom serialiser could look like below:

```
class FlattenableJsonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Flattenable> {

    private final JsonSerializer<Object> base;

    public FlattenableJsonSerializer(JsonSerializer base) {
        this.base = Objects.requireNonNull(base);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Flattenable value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
        if (value.isFlattened()) {
            gen.writeObject(value.flatten());
        } else {
            base.serialize(value, gen, serializers);
        }
    }
}
```

When we have `POJO` model and serialiser we need to only configure `ObjectMapper` and try to use our solution:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.BeanDescription;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.json.JsonMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerModifier;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class JsonFlattenApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SimpleModule flattenModule = new SimpleModule("FlattenModule");
        flattenModule.setSerializerModifier(new FlattenableBeanSerializerModifier());

        ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder()
                .addModule(flattenModule)
                .build();

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Foo(true, 1)));
        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Foo(false, 2)));
    }
}

class FlattenableBeanSerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier {
    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> modifySerializer(SerializationConfig config, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonSerializer<?> serializer) {
        if (Flattenable.class.isAssignableFrom(beanDesc.getBeanClass())) {
            return new FlattenableJsonSerializer(serializer);
        }

        return serializer;
    }
}
```

Above code prints two lines:

```
//1
{"id":1,"random":0.7818309762014325}

//2
{"flattened":false,"id":2}
```

Answer (score 0):

As suspected, there is a way to disable a specific annotation. In this case, I wanted to disable the `JsonSerialize` annotation on the `Foo` class. So, I did this to break the infinite loop:

```
public class FooSerializer extends StdSerializer<Foo>
{
    @Override
    public void serialize(
        final Foo foo,
        final JsonGenerator jsonGenerator,
        final SerializerProvider serializerProvider)
        throws IOException
    {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JacksonAnnotationIntrospector annotationIntrospector =
            new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector()
        {
            @Override
            protected <A extends Annotation> A _findAnnotation(
                final Annotated annotated,
                final Class<A> annotationClass)
            {
                if (annotated.hasAnnotation(JsonSerialize.class) &&
                    annotated.getRawType() == Foo.class)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                return super._findAnnotation(annotated, annotationClass);
            }
        };
        mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(annotationIntrospector);
        jsonGenerator.setCodec(mapper);

        if (foo.isFlattened())
        {
            jsonGenerator.writeObject(flatten(foo));
        }
        else
        {
            jsonGenerator.writeObject(foo);
        }
    }

    private Map<String,Object> flatten(Foo foo)
    {
        // ... some logic that builds the Map...
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution looks little bit like a hack. For every serialisation process, it will create new `ObjectMapper` with custom implementation of  `JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` which disables custom serialiser for `Foo`. Also, overwriting codec by `jsonGenerator.setCodec(mapper)` could have drawbacks because all other objects in the process will be serialised by this instance of `ObjectMapper`. In case you need to use some custom or common modules, for `Java 8`, `Java 8 Time`, etc. classes you would have to register them again every time in your custom serialiser. Consider to use mine solution.